# Merging multiple json file into one object using JQ with argument

Tags: json, jq

I have thousands of JSON file that I want to merge in one object. Those all are not in a similar format. Let me explain in detail. Here is the first sample of JSON

```
[
  {
    "value 1": 1,
    "value 2": 2,
    "value 3": 3,
    "value 4": 4
  }
]
```

and another types are not similar, something like following having few common fields and other fields

```
[
  {
    "value 3": 300,
    "value 4": 400,
    "value 5": 500,
    "value 6": 600
  }
]
```

Such as I have 2 file having first sample format and one file having second example format. I am trying to using `jq` for merging this.

```
jq -s '.' *.json > myfile.json
```

It is returning the following with three different objects

```
[
  {
    "value 1": 1,
    "value 2": 2,
    "value 3": 3,
    "value 4": 4
  }
],
[
  {
    "value 1": 10,
    "value 2": 20,
    "value 3": 30,
    "value 4": 40
  }
],
[
  {
    "value 3": 300,
    "value 4": 400,
    "value 5": 500,
    "value 6": 600
  }
]
```

I need to merge this into one object like following and if there any `jq` option to exclude those files that have specific field. Something like excluding those files which have the field `"value 6"`. So finally the JSON output will be

```
[
  {
    "value 1": 1,
    "value 2": 2,
    "value 3": 3,
    "value 4": 4
  },
  {
    "value 1": 10,
    "value 2": 20,
    "value 3": 30,
    "value 4": 40
  }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `inputs` to apply the filter on the contents of all the JSON files together and apply the select filter. The `-n` flag is to ensure the output JSON is constructed from scratch from the given input.

```
jq -n '[ inputs[] | select( has("value 6") | not ) ]' *.json
```

By doing `jq -n 'inputs[]'`, all the objects in all the constituent JSON files are made available to the select function which discards any object containing key field as `"value 6"`. The `[..]` surrounding the filter is put the final resultant objects within the array.

Another way would be to use a `reduce()` function to add the required objects in an iterative way

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs[] as $data (.; . + [ if $data | has("value 6") | not then $data else empty end ] )'
```

Comment: That's work like magic....hundred of thousands file merged within 1 hour. Can you help a little bit more? How can I remove duplicate? Something like, if `"value 3"` is duplicate of any other value then duplicate object will not merge. Thanks

Comment: @Devil'sDream: Happy to be of help. But your question is completely new. I'm afraid I can't modify my current answer to your new requirement. Can you post a new question?

Comment: I have posted a new question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588098/413732

Answer (score 0):

I created a command line tool using Node.js to merge nested json files locally.

https://github.com/divyeshmakwana96/injson

You can use `!include('./path-to-json/item1.json')` statement to embed contents of another json file. The child json files could also have include statement.

**Example:**

```
{
  "pi": 3.141,
  "happy": true,
  "questions:": [
    "!include('./questions/item1.json')",
    "!include('./questions/item2.json')"
  ],
  "answer": "!include('./answers/item1.json')"
}
```