# Merging multiple JSON files removing duplicate objects by a field

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to merging hundreds of thousand JSON files that have a single object. with the help of this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588083/413732) I have successfully added all objects into a single object as an array. Now I want to filter out some objects during merge if a specific field or parameter is duplicate. Something like `field 1` of two objects have the same value.

Here is the example

Input File 1:

```
[
    {
      "field 1": 10,
      "field 2": 25,
      "field 3": 35,
      "field 4": 45
    }
]
```

Input file 2:

```
[
    {
      "field 1": 15,
      "field 2": 25,
      "field 3": 35,
      "field 4": 45
    }
]
```

Input file 3:

```
[
    {
      "field 1": 10,
      "field 2": 20,
      "field 3": 30,
      "field 4": 40
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
      "field 1": 10,
      "field 2": 25,
      "field 3": 35,
      "field 4": 45
    },
    {
      "field 1": 15,
      "field 2": 25,
      "field 3": 35,
      "field 4": 45
    }
]
```

The file 3 object will not merge due to having `field 1` value same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just use the `unique_by()` function in `jq` which expects an array of objects and takes the field name as the input to remove duplicates on

```
jq -n '[ inputs[] ] | unique_by(."value 1")'
```

To append on top of my other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588083/413732) to uniquely select based on one field and remove objects by another field you can do below. The below code groups objects excluding duplicates based on `"value 1"` and excludes ones containing `"value 6"`

```
jq -n '[ [inputs[]] | unique_by(."value 1")[] | select( has("value 6") | not )]  '
```